# start a new branch with the last commit in the new branch

Tags: git

I am currently working with this git tree/workflow

```
A [master]
 \
  B ------------- D [develop] 
   \             / 
    C1 -- C2 -- C3 -- C4 [feature1]
```

Now i wanted to create a new branch for the 2nd feature but i forgot to check out the new branch and i commited new code to the Feature1 branch.

```
A [master]
 \
  B ------------- D [develop] 
   \             / 
    C1 -- C2 -- C3 [feature2]
                 \
                  C4 [feature2]
```

So what i want to do now it to remove C4 form the feature 1 branche and add it to the feature 2 branche which is still non existent. C4 is not yet pushed to the remote, the rest of the project is.

Comment: Your ASCII graphs are unclear/ambiguous. Please read the remarks at the top of [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488138/move-initial-commits-off-master-to-another-branch-in-git/25490288#25490288), and correct your graphs so we know exactly where your branches are pointing. Only then will people here be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Make sure you have a clean working state (create a stash if you need to). At this stage, your repo still looks like this:

   ```
   A [master]
    \
     B ------------- D [develop] 
      \             / 
       C1 -- C2 -- C3 
                    \
                     C4 [feature1]
   ```
2. Create and check out a branch called `feature2` that points at the same commit as `feature1` does:

   ```
   git checkout -b feature2 feature1
   ```

   Your repo will then look like this:

   ```
   A [master]
    \
     B ------------- D [develop] 
      \             / 
       C1 -- C2 -- C3
                    \
                     C4 [HEAD=feature2,feature1]
   ```
3. Reset the `feature1` branch by one commit:

   ```
   git checkout feature1
   git reset --hard HEAD^
   ```

   Your repo will then look like this:

   ```
   A [master]
    \
     B ------------- D [develop] 
      \             / 
       C1 -- C2 -- C3 [HEAD=feature1]
                    \
                     C4 [feature2]
   ```
4. If you want to continue working on the `feature2` branch, check it out (and also pop your last stash, if you created one):

   ```
   git checkout feature2
   ```

   Your repo will then look like this:

   ```
   A [master]
    \
     B ------------- D [develop] 
      \             / 
       C1 -- C2 -- C3 [feature1]
                    \
                     C4 [HEAD=feature2]
   ```