# Remove commits from git rebased branch after other commits were done

Tags: git, rebase, revert

I have a project with two branches called **master** and **feature/x**. On **feature/x** I'm working on new features that will be merged on master.

For mistake on **feature/x** a rebase action based on master was done and pushed. Besides other commits were done and pushed on **feature/x**.

So I have two branches that contain "same commits" marked by different hash.

```
A -- B -- C -- D [master]
 \
  E -- F -- G -- H -- I [feature/x]
```

where `C` and `D` on **master** are respectively the same commits (rebased) of `F` and `G` on **feature/x**.

I would like to remove `F` and `G` from **feature/x** maintaining `H` and `I`. How can I do it?

I'm thinking to revert commit

```
git revert F G
```

from **feature/x** but those useless (duplicate) commits will remain in the history. I would know if there are better way to do it?

Comment: You shouldn't label your branches on the left-hand side like you did here; see  the top of [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488138/move-initial-commits-off-master-to-another-branch-in-git/25490288#25490288).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to rebase interactively: checkout `feature/x`, and do

```
git rebase -i E
```

then just delete the lines for F, G from the rebase script you're prompted to edit. This will create leave your branches looking like

```
master   -> A -- B -- C -- D
                  \
feaure/x ->        E -- H' -- I'
                    \
(orphaned)           F -- G -- H -- I
```

You can do the same thing with

```
git rebase --onto E G feature/x
```

but the interactive method is much easier to remember (I had to look up the argument order in the online help).

---

Note that the old commits still exist, and are recoverable, but will eventually be garbage-collected if nothing refers to them.

Comment: @bato only if `feature/x` was pushed into the remote repository.

Comment: @Zeeker yes it was :(

Comment: In that case, remember it affects everyone who _pulled_ from the remote repo, as well.

Comment: @Useless yes I know. Luckily only another person is working on it.