# Git - refusing to merge unrelated histories when pulling from previously used origin

Tags: git, bitbucket

I set a new url to previously used origin in our server as

```
git remote set-url origin [new_url]
```

Now there's an error when I'm trying to pull

```
git pull origin dev
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I set the new url beacuse i don't want to create a new origin for doing stuff.
How can I solve this?

Edit :-

When added the git pull origin dev --allow-unrelated-histories an error comes up again. and some untrack files are shown

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
```

I want to overwritten the files

Comment: Duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38255655/trying-to-pull-files-from-my-github-repository-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-his/40959920
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase ?

Comment: *"When added the git pull origin dev --allow-unrelated-histories an error comes up again. and some untrack files are shown
`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:`

I want to overwritten the files"* - Just delete the listet files manually

Comment: It may sound like a duplicate because the first error message is the same, but the scenario with the `git remote set-url` command is a little different

Answer (score 1):

A `git pull` is just a combination of `git fetch` + `git merge`. The fetch operation should basically be conflict-less, so the problem arises from the merge part. If that merge is just a fast-forward, it's not really a merge and we can do a reset instead (i.e. `git fetch` + `git reset` instead of `git pull`).

I am assuming a few things first:

1. You have no modified files when starting.
2. Your `dev` branch contains no un-published commits.

Under those conditions you can replace `git pull origin dev` with the following:

```bash
git branch backup-of-dev-just-in-case dev
git fetch origin
git checkout dev
git reset --hard origin/dev   # This command is like "rm -rf", you should always double
                              # check conditions every time you use `--hard` so that you
                              # do not accidentally delete too much.
```

---

In case your dev branch did contain un-pushed commits, do the following additional steps:

```bash
git branch local-dev-changes backup-of-dev-just-in-case
git rebase --rebase-merges dev local-dev-changes
git checkout dev
git merge local-dev-changes
git branch -d local-dev-changes
```