# GIT Fatal : refusing to merge unrelated histories

Tags: git, bitbucket

```
$ git pull origin master
From https://bitbucket.org/tecgenome/chl-v2.0-html
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

How can I avoid or get past that error message?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[Since Git 2.9 (April 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528527/6309), you can try:

```
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin master
```

But check why those branches are no longer common though.
Maybe there was a force push rewriting *all* the history of `origin/master`.

In which case, if you don't have local commits of your own, it is best to reset your branch to the new one:

**Warning**: this will delete any untracked file, and reset your repository to **origin/master**
(You can try it in a copy of your current local clone)

```
git fetch

# Warning: RESET AHEAD
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem. Not sure what `pull` has to do with a merge problem firstly and the second solution you give still doesn't fix the merge problem.

Comment: I used Knight2016's solution.

Comment: not blaming the person who answered just sharing my experience, i attempted this solution and it deleted almost all of my local work, thankfully no harm done, however for those who don't know *this will delete local work which isnt in the remote git repo*

Comment: @LiamO'Toole I am sorry to read that. I have edited the answer to better highlight the "reset" effect and its danger.

Answer (score 15):

I did meet the same issue, and try the command it gets work.

`git merge abbranch --allow-unrelated-histories`

here we assume that `abbranch` is unrelated to current branch. Above command merge `abbranch` to current branch.

Comment: In may case, and using the principle @knight206 points to, `git merge origin/master --allow-unrelated-histories` worked.

Answer (score -1):

if you are facing **push Recjected** or this issue in android studio
you just open your project **enable version control integration**

and Move to project from android.
right click on package --> go to Git --> Add

now come on downside click on **terminal**  and 
follow given below step

```
 git remote add origin <repository url>

    git clone <repository url>
    git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
    git merge origin origin/master
    ... add and commit here...
    git push origin master
```