# Combine two git folders

Tags: git

I've currently a git repository that I uploaded to GitHub. When I was to my school, I wanted to develop the code and downlad the repository (without the "`.gi`t" folder, so I just got the code itself).

I did many changes and committed multiple times, but now I'm home I want to merge the new commits I made on the new folder on the old one.

Here is an example :

*Original folder*

```
Initial commit [with no code]
Commit 1
Commit 2
```

*New folder*

```
New initial commit (with the code of commit 2)
Commit 3
Commit 4
Commit 5
```

Now I want to add **Commit 3**, **Commit 4** and **Commit 5** to the *original folder*. How can I do it ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but is not as simple as moving the new folder to the original folder?

Comment: No, because the commits I made on the original folder are not done in the new folder. In the new one, which contains the code after `Commit 2`, I initialized a **new** git repository and made commits in it. Now I want to add the commits I made on the new repository to the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch one repo in the other, and then if you want merge them

A merge would only be possible [since git 2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36528527/6309) if the branches has no common history

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories a b
```

In your case, you could directly [pull from the second repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40037123/6309):

```
git remote add second_repo /path/to/second/repo
git pull second_repo master
```

That will be enough to get the commits from the second repo back into the first one.

Comment: The method you gave doesn't work, when I perform the `git pull` command it says me `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. Also, when I do `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories second_repo master`, it shows me that there are conflicts in the code, but it doesn't seem to be any conflict in files...

Comment: @ClementNerma git status will list you the files to fix