# How do I squash commits on a branch that has children

Tags: git, rebase, squash

So I have a situation with a master and a bugfix branch that continues it. I tried squashing some commits on master and then rebasing bugfix on it but I got merge conflicts. What is the proper way to do it ? I work locally and there is no remote.

It looks like this :

```
A - B - C - D - E - F [master]
                     \                 
                      G - H - I - J - K [bugfix]
```

I want to squash A - B - C - D - E - F and still have bugfix continuing the squashed master branch.

Comment: To get a helpful answer, you should tell us more. Tell us what part (if any) of your repo's history has been pushed to a shared remote, and perhaps add an ASCII commit graph (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488138/move-initial-commits-off-master-to-another-branch-in-git/25490288#25490288), for instance) that describes your recent history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jubob's point about shared history is a very important one, as rebasing or squashing shared commits is strongly discouraged.

I will assume that you are working with local commits.

Suppose you started with this:

```
[master] A---B---C---D
                      \
[bugfix]               1---2---3
```

and you decided to squash `B`, `C` and `D` into a new commit `D'`

```
[master] A---D'
          \
[bugfix]   B---C---D---1---2---3
```

Note that commits `B`, `C` and `D` remain in the `bugfix` branch. If you simply rebase `bugfix` onto `master`, Git will try to do this:

```
[master] A---D'
              \
[bugfix]       B---C---D---1---2---3
```

But the changes introduced by `B`, `C` and `D` are already contained in `D'`. What you really want to end up with is this:

```
[master] A---D'
              \
[bugfix]       1---2---3
```

You can accomplish this with the `--onto` option of [`rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git rebase --onto master D bugfix
```

`D` should be the latest commit in `bugfix` that should *not* be included when rebasing.