# How to nuke a commit before last commit

Tags: git

Suppose I have 2 branches `master` and `dev`.

The `dev` branch is ahead of `master` by 2 commits, and neither of those commits is merged or pushed to any `remote`.

The `dev` branch looks like this:

```
dev A - B - C - D - E
```

Whereas, A is oldest, and E newest commit.

Id like to get to this state:

```
dev A - B - C - E
```

Basically I want to nuke the commit before the last commit, as if it never happened. There should be no conflicts either (E does not depend on D's changes).

Could I use interactive rebase?

Comment: See my comment at the top of http://stackoverflow.com/a/25490288/2541573

Comment: Instead of "Nuke" a better wording may be to have C be the parent of E instead of D.  If nothing then points to D it will eventually be garbage collected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the itneractive form of rebase. While on `dev` (you need to have clean working copy):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~~
```

In your favourite text editor, you get a list of last 2 commits. Just comment/delete the line for the unwanted commit.

If `HEAD` depends on changes introduced by `HEAD~`, you could get merge conflicts and after you resolve them, you will loose your previous history (still available through the `reflog`, of course). I usually prefer this method.

If you want to conserve your previous history (and the unneeded commit), you should do

```
git checkout HEAD~~         # go to last good commit
git checkout -b new_branch  # create a new branch and forget about the original
git cherry_pick dev         # copy the commit on top of `dev` to `new_branch`
```

You will still get a conflict, but you won't be modifying the history of `dev`.

<sub>On the other hand, if the unwanted commit was on `master` and you didn't want to break anybody's build, you would do `git revert HEAD~`</sub>

Comment: Ahh, in the end I couldn't avoid merge conflict anyway. Resolved both. Thanks.

Comment: @JanNetherdrake, you can either modify `E` to resolve the conflict, or go to a new branch. Expanded on that in the answer. Btw I love `rebase -i` - you can reorder, split, squash, rename etc. commits.