# Moving all changes from master branch to dev branch

Tags: git

Inside my local `master` branch I made significant changes. I forgot first to create and switch to my `workingbranch` before. Now I need this changes on remote branch but not on remote master branch which is still intact.

My question is:
what is the best way to copy this local `master` branch into new `workingbranch` and then to replicate remote master branch to local one?

Comment: To get better help, you should add an ASCII graph of your repo, like in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488138/move-initial-commits-off-master-to-another-branch-in-git/25490288#25490288).

Comment: I'll mark this as a duplicate, but if it's not the same problem, edit the question to provide the relevant details, comment with @torek, and I'll re-open it (or you can just write a new question with the details that distinguish it from the other case).